# How do I periodically refresh the data in an RDS table automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a web application that uses two databases. I want to schedule an SQL query to be executed in set intervals to select data from the first database and put it in a table in the second one and the web application takes it's data from here.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use-case? Is it simply duplicating tables, or is it performing a transformation on the data? What type of databases are they (MySQL, Postgres, etc)? Are they both the same database? Where are the databases running (on Amazon RDS)? Is it a complex SQL that takes considerable time to process, or is it rather quick? (The reason I ask is that Lambda functions are limited to 15 minutes.) How much data are you talking about (MBs, GBs)? Please edit your question to add these details rather than answering via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a scheduled Lambda function.

From Schedule jobs for Amazon RDS and Aurora PostgreSQL using Lambda and Secrets Manager

> For on-premises databases and databases that are hosted on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances, database administrators often use the cron utility to schedule jobs. For example, a job for data extraction or a job for data purging can easily be scheduled using cron. For these jobs, database credentials are typically either hard-coded or stored in a properties file. However, when you migrate to Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) or Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL, you lose the ability to log in to the host instance to schedule cron jobs.  This pattern describes how to use AWS Lambda and AWS Secrets Manager to schedule jobs for Amazon RDS and Aurora PostgreSQL databases after migration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/schedule-jobs-for-amazon-rds-and-aurora-postgresql-using-lambda-and-secrets-manager.html